# IE7 element can't be clicked

Tags: html, css, dom, internet-explorer-7

I've narrowed a defect down to this sample, where the numeral "1" is unclickable in IE7 (only):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Click 1</title>
    <style type="text/css">     
        div   { position: absolute; overflow: auto; }
        table { position: relative; }
        span  { position: fixed; top: 100px; }
    </style>
</head><body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <span onclick='alert(1)'>1</span>2
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Can anyone identify the root cause, so I understand my options for workarounds?

I'm using all the CSS represented here to build a sortable fixed head scrolling table. In the original code, the span actually lives in a TH, fixing the headings above the scrolling table via negative margin, while allowing the table renderer to account for the header text in column width, without table duplication or 'onResize'-simulating timers.

Comment: Have you defined `sortTable()` ?

Comment: I used thirtydot's example to demonstrate that the javascript isn't related to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `position: relative` from `div` fixes it.

If that's not an option, I also found adding `*display: inline` to `div` fixes it.

The asterisk before `display` is a CSS  hack to apply the rule to only IE7 and below. It's not an awesome one to use because it is not valid CSS, but it works and causes no problems.

If neither of these ideas works for you, it would be helpful to see a more complete test case to understand why.

---

Your original code, but with `<span onclick='alert(1)'>` so the JavaScript works:
http://jsbin.com/aretu5 *(can't click it in IE7)*

Same, with `position: relative` removed:
http://jsbin.com/aretu5/2 *(works in IE7)*

Same, with `position: relative` still there and `*display: inline` added:
http://jsbin.com/aretu5/3 *(works in IE7)*

Comment: But it's fixed with `inline` (for some odd reason..) ?

Comment: @thirtydot: on the DIV I was using ABSOLUTE (plus TOP: and BOTTOM:) to take the page size minus header plus footer. RELATIVE has the same issue. On the TABLE I used relative to permit shifting the position of some contained elements.

Comment: @thirtydot I'm going crazy, your link with the *display hack works for me, but now I can't replicate it on my local test jig. I'm still looking at it.

Comment: @shannon: Post the test case you're using, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @thirtydot: the problem in my testcase was absolute vs. relative on the DIV. inline fixes the relative case, but not the absolute case. crazy badness here, and I still don't understand the root cause. My actual app has about 200 CSS declarations and frankly I'm not sure when this particular IE7 unclickable element crept in. I'd be happy to share test credentials with you on our public test site if you are interested.

Comment: ps. I'm looking for a way to replace the whole use of "fixed" with absolute. I think it can be done with a few wrapping divs to resolve other IE7 defects. GAH, someone put that damn browser out of its freakin' misery!!!

Comment: @shannon: Send a link to the email in [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/), and I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: @thirtydot: Done. Note I've got positioning problems under the current technique for header location. http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=615364&page=4 shows various approaches to this problem.  I think if I just give in to adding divs specifically to address this IE7 defect I'll probably be fine.  Just trying to wrap my head around it.  FIXED is dicey, even between Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I did look at the test site, but it was very confusing and I couldn't figure it out after 30 mins, so I gave up.

Comment: I have not fixed it yet. Glad you got the link.  Yeah I figured it wouldn't really help - there's just too much going on there, plus it doesn't help that our public test site java and css are minimized, and most of the content comes from JSON.  That's why I narrowed it down so much and didn't post the original source here.  I mainly gave it to you since you asked.

Answer (score 1):

try to use brackets

```
<span onclick='sortTable()'>1</span>
```